# What are the customizations when using the facebook like iframe within my webpage?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I have the following code to show

```
  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=[mySite]"
                    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
                    style="border:none; width:170px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

which works great but I wanted to see if i could customize it to:

1. Not show which one of my friends like it.  So instead of saying:

   ***Joe Thompson and 100 other people like this***

I just want it to say:

***100 people like this***

basically I am trying to fit this like button in a small area of real estate on the page adn I want to have more certainly around what will show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ change that line of text to read specifically how you want.  It can be removed all together yet still show the like count if you change `layout` to `button_count`.  However with this option, iframe is not available to use, so you'll need to change over to XFBML or HTML5.

Comment: are you saying this flexibility (to not show names but just the text 100 people like this) is available when using XFBML ?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ change that line of text to read specifically how you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one just change [Enter Your Page URL] with your URL

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?[Enter Your Page URL]&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21&amp;appId=201523196612824" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I want it to show "100 people like this".  I just don't want it to show friends names

Comment: yes you can see here there is parameter show_faces=false goes to facebook which will disable people faces or name and just show count, you just copy and paste with replacing your url.

Comment: Sorry the names still appear with show_faces=false.  Try it out on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/.